# While & If loop expected error

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that would read in numbers from the keyboard, compute the average of the numbers, and display it. The sequence of numbers are to be terminated with a zero.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int count;
    double number, sum, average;

    count = 0;
    sum = 0;
    average = 0;

    cout << "\nEnter Number (0 to terminate): ";
    cin >> number;

    while(number! = 0.0)
    {
        sum = sum + number;
        count = count + 1;
        cout << "\nEnter Number: ";
        cin >> number;
    }
    if(count! = 0.0);
    {
        average = sum/count;
    }

    cout << "\nThe average of the" << count << "number is" << average << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting two errors:

> expected ')'

and

> if statement has empty body

Comment: If you want to share solution post an answer, don't put solutions in the question. Question posts are only for holding questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not insert any whitespaces between your comparators.

You wrote `(number! = 0.0)`, but the correct one should be: `(number != 0.0)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int count;
    double number, sum, average;

    count = 0;
    sum = 0;
    average = 0;

    cout << "\nEnter Number (0 to terminate): ";
    cin >> number;

    while(number != 0.0)
    {
        sum = sum + number;
        count = count + 1;
        cout << "\nEnter Number: ";
        cin >> number;
    }
    if(count != 0.0)
    {
        average = sum/count;
    }

    cout << "\nThe average of the" << count << "number is" << average << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(count! = 0.0);
```

Get rid of semicolon

Answer (score 1):

There are three errors:

- The `!=` operator is mis-spelled `! =`  in two places.
- The `if` has a semicolon after the closing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You have a semi-colon (;) right after the if statement.  Remove it :)

```
if(count! = 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`while(number! = 0.0)` should be `while(number != 0.0)`

and

`if(count! = 0.0)` should be `if(count != 0.0)`

Note `!=` is an operator but `! =` is not - attention to the details!